# How to display average in C++?

Tags: c++

in my c++ class, for part of a project I have to "Compute the student's current overall average and display it. The midterm counts 20%, the project average counts 40%, and the homework average counts 15% "Your current average is XX%". There are no numeric grades given to calculate the average in the assignment just percentages. Do i have to factor in these % into the average and if so how do i do that. I'm a beginner. Here is the code i have done for this part of the project.

```
average = ( _midtermgrade + _projectaverage + _homeworkaverage / 3);
cout << "Your currentaverage is" << average <<endl;
```

Comment: Before you write the code, try figuring out an equation that will give you the correct value.

Comment: Do you know what a weighted average is? Check this out: http://www.wikihow.com/Calculate-Weighted-Average

Comment: This isn't programming (yet)  - it's just basic math.

Comment: I just want to know if i have to include the percentages from the assignment into the average equation? Or is it fine as I have it now?

Answer (score 1):

To compute a weighted average, sum each score multiplied by its weight and then divide the total by the total weight.

For example:

```
average = ((_midtermgrade * 20 + _projectaverage * 40 + _homeworkaverage * 15)
    / (20 + 40 + 15));
cout << "Your currentaverage is" << average <<endl;
```

Comment: Ok thanks David. Like i said im a beginner and am trying hard to learn this stuff.